# Is it required to perform a copy of entries while iterating from one container when filling another?

Tags: c++

When I have a function like this:

```
std::vector<std::experimental::filesystem::directory_entry> Foo(const std::string& start)
{
    std::vector<std::experimental::filesystem::directory_entry> result;

    auto paths = std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator(start);

    for (auto& d : paths) {
        if (IsDirectory(d)) {
            result.push_back(d);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

is it required to perform a copy of directory entry when iterating over the `paths` collection with using `auto d` instead of `auto& d`?

My intuition says the following:

1. While iterating `paths` returns a reference of `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::directory_entry&` type.
2. Which I then pass to the vector whose `push_back` has the following signature: `void push_back (const value_type& val)`

Which I think means that after I return a vector from function it would contain elements that refer to the memory that already was reclaimed, hence I'm in trouble.

So the question: do I have to replace it with `auto d` or am I missing something?

Comment: _"...or am I missing something? ..."_ Yes, the `const` in the `push_back ()` signature. `std::vector` doesn't store references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `push_back` will do a copy to take ownership of the object.

As long as `vector` is declared to contain objects, regardless you can `push_back` with a reference, a const reference or an object, the `vector` will always store objects, never references.